# Taking a vector<char> as a parameter and then converting to string

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

```
void conversionToString(vector<char>& x) {
    string s(x.begin(), x.end());
    cout << s;
}
int main() {
    vector<char> test('a', 'b', 'c');
    conversionToString(test);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to take a string and convert into a vector of char. In this sample I am just doing a simple test, but in my actual project I plan on taking user input and converting back and forth from a vector too a string. Using compile online, I get the error message:

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::vector(char, char, char)’
     vector test('a', 'b', 'c');

I was hoping to get some advice on not only fixing this method, but on the functionality of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector initialization is wrong. You need

```
vector<char> test{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Concerning the functionality of the method, I don't see much point in the conversion. You can print the vector's elements:

```
for (auto c : test)
{
  std::cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. I need to convert it to a vector so the string can be dealt with in reverse polish notation - I have more detail in a response to another answer below.

Comment: @user3521441 I still cannot see why you need the transformations.

Comment: What would your suggestion be? Taking a complicated user input as a string and converting to vector<char> and then reverse polish notation seems to be the most efficient to me to handle complicated computations

Comment: @user3521441 I would probably skip the conversion to vector part.

Comment: How would I be able to handle the simplification of several computations in the form on a single string?

Comment: @user3521441: you would just loop over the characters -- `string test = "123"; for( auto c: test ) { std::cout << c; }` has the same effect as the answer above. You don't need a `std::vector`; a `std::string` is a container of `char`, with `begin()` and `end()` etc... any algorithms applicable to `vector` are also applicable to `string`.

Comment: @user3521441 Is there anything can you do with a `vector<char>` that you can't do with a `string`? If so, then yes, convert to vector. But I can't think of anything.

Comment: As a beginner, I had the concept of a string as a single entity, no matter what it contained. I did not make the connection that it is simply a container for characters. So string can be treated as a group of individual chars, not including spaces, and then manipulate them how I want?

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for vectors should look like this (C++11 only):

```
vector<char> test{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

In general, it is questionable if you should convert "back and forth from a vector too a string" - why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is correct: he is using the wrong constructor. Also, you bring up a good question: I'm guessing he wants to read user input character by character into a `vector<char>`, convert it into a `string`, and then do some stuff with it.

Comment: We are working on creating a functioning calculator that takes user input as a string. From there I am converting that string to a vector. The user input will be something like "1+3-7*8" and then, once inside the vector, it will be converted to "reverse polish notation." After calculations are made it will need to be returned to the console as a string in its final answer. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In the context of a school project (as it sounds like), this is fine. There might be better ways to do it and you could avoid some copies, but you'll get to that soon enough. No need to worry about that for now.

Comment: Yes, it is the second of a 2 part programming class (java -> c++) in university. This situation is a group project handling a lot of situations

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11, you can use an initializer list with `vector<char>`:

```
vector<char> test{'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

If you aren't using C++11, you'll have to do this the slow way:

```
vector<char> test;
test.push_back('a');
test.push_back('b');
test.push_back('c');
```

Answer (score -1):

You are taking a vector of characters already in your function. Please rephrase your question. If you want to take an std::string and return std::vector, here is a function that will do it:

```
std::vector<char> StringToChar(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<char> charVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        charVector.push_back(str.at(i));
    }

    return charVector;
}
```

Comment: Just `std::vector<char> v(str.begin(), str.end());` would do and would be more efficient.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK, but that does not mean that my solution does not do the job. So please vote up.